# jquery- how to run some code within a form only when some text within that form is selected by the user

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run some code only when the user has selected some text within the form- the selected text may be the label of an input element within the form, or some text directly given within the form.

Currently I am using the following--

```
$('form').each(function(){
    // the 'this' below refers to a form- any element within the form is a child of the form...
    //hence the listener checks for focus being set to any element within any form of the web page...
    $(this).children().focus(function() {

  ......MY CODE HERE.............
```

Is there a better way to modify the code above, so that it works only when the user has selected some text within the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

```
$("form *").focus(function () { 
alert("focus"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's javascript for looking at text selection but it';s in some ways more of a mess than the DOM APIs. I don't have a full solution for you but look at [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) for a sane selection API and register events to something like mouseup to check the current selection.